# CSS shine up of pod2html output

Tags: man, html

Let us just agree that [the output of pod2html](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html) is boooring.

Is there a tool that adds some CSS/HTML5 to make it a bit less 1990s?

Answer (score 1):

Does the `--css` flag not work? Or do you want to actually embed the CSS in the generated HTML?

In both cases, it should be relatively easy to add the functionality to Pod::Html (on my home machine I have Perl 5.26.1 and this is around line 370).

This is a very basic attempt (my Perl is more than a bit rusty), modifying said Html.pm module around line 370:

```
if ($Css) {
    if ($Css =~ /^@/) {
            $Css = substr($Css, 1);
            open my $csh, '<', $Css or die "Error opening CSS file for inclusion";
            read $csh, my $style, -s $csh;
            $csslink = qq(\n<style type="text/css">\n$style</style>\n");
    } else {
            $csslink = qq(\n<link rel="stylesheet" href="$Css" type="text/css" />);
            $csslink =~ s,\\,/,g;
            $csslink =~ s,(/.):,$1|,;
    }
    $tdstyle= '';
}
```

The modification allows to specify a CSS not only by URL but by path, by prepending a "@" to the path name. I.e.

```
pod2html ... --css @/home/lserni/tests/pod.css ...
```

The CSS will be embedded (no checks, no parsing, no warnings! Possible to include malicious tags and whatever) into the HTML file.

It would also be easy to modify the flag so that if the CSS is not supplied and is not in stdin, instead of the error **a default CSS is used** (simply set `$csslink` to an appropriate value instead of dying 'Error opening CSS'). The CSS would have to be pre-supplied in the code (*and possibly overridden in a ~/.podhtmlrc file?*)

<sup><sup><sup>It goes without saying that whoever wished to polish this hack and send it to whoever it may concern is allowed, encouraged and more than welcome to do so; any credit goes to them.</sup></sup></sup>

Comment: `--css` requires me to write some CSS. I do not want that. I want `pod2html` to generate some reasonable default, that looks like it was designed post 2000.

Comment: @OleTange I have updated the answer and added how to creep that feature in :-)

Answer (score 1):

I agree the default output is very 1990s. I'm working on a [Pull Request](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/pull/17987) to update `pod2html` to use HTML5 and some simple CSS right now.

I'd love to collaborate on some best practices for simple CSS for `pod2html` stuff.

Comment: I will be happy to give feedback if you post some examples, that are done with your changes. I will not comment on the actual CSS code (my CSS skills are quite limited), but more on the UX side, if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try **Raku**'s `Pod::to::HTML` module?

https://raku.land/github:Raku/Pod::To::HTML
https://github.com/Raku/Pod-To-HTML

Apparently, you can find a `css-url` you like and see if that spruces up your Pod-To-HTML conversion (according to the [README.md](https://github.com/Raku/Pod-To-HTML/blob/0d94e0d4077d68b78383ecc2616a0ae50161f347/README.md) file):

*"Additional information can be made available to the Mustache template by supplying to `render` as named arguments. For example, `css-url => https://design.raku.org/perl.css` will be available to the template as `css-url`."*

---

---

Alternatively, there's **Raku**'s `Raku::Pod::Render` module:

https://raku.land/zef:finanalyst/Raku::Pod::Render
https://github.com/finanalyst/raku-pod-render
https://github.com/finanalyst/raku-pod-render/releases

Richard Hainsworth (a.k.a. @finalyst) has been working on his
`Raku::Pod::Render` module, which is used in production to render Raku's Documentation site. The 'about' blurb reads as follows:

*"Renders Raku POD to HTML, or MarkDown. GUI to take POD from a Module and create a README.md from it. Other output formats possible by changing templates."*